# Get Content Type of Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, rest, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mime

To find the incoming content type, [docs say](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-headers):

```
 request.headers["Content-Type"] # => "text/plain"
```

But I found by trial-and-error, that doesn't work, but this does:

```
 request.headers["CONTENT_TYPE"]=='application/json'
```

So what's the most robust+portable way to do it?

Comment: What version of rails are you working with ?

Comment: Judging by the tags he attached, probably 3.1

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I would usually go for `request.format` and `request.content_type` for reading these header fields.

**EDIT**: found a bit more on this that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1595453/624590

Comment: #binding.pry
    respond_to do |format|
    if (request.content_type == "application/json")
      format.json {render json: @user}
    elsif  (request.content_type == "application/xml")
      format.xml {render xml: @user}
    else
      format.html
    end
   end

Answer (score 26):

You don't need to parse the content_type string, Rails has already done this for you. Just check:

```
request.format.symbol == :json
```

Answer (score 24):

Another way of writing it:

```
request.format.json?
```

Comment: But if the request accept header is */*, it will still be false, right?

Answer (score 12):

No need to call #symbol since equals is overloaded:

```
request.format == :json
```

Answer (score 3):

For me the best way to check if incoming request is a json was:

```
    if request.content_type =~ /json/
```

Answer (score 2):

request.format == 'application/json'

Answer (score 2):

Seriously require focus to understand here. Ref. Rails 6.x with api only project

You have to make sure why you want `request.content_type` OR `request.headers['Content-Type']` ? Explained below...

1. `request.format` OR `request.headers['Accept']` is what format client is expecting to request's response by API(Service or Server).
2. `request.content_type` OR `request.headers['Content-Type']` is what API(Service or Server) is expecting data format from request.

So if API(Service or Server) wants to request's data in `application/json` then you are right with request.content_type OR `request.headers['Content-Type']`

Answer (score 0):

I think all the **previous answers are misleading a bit**, although some of them are correct, and the most precise one is not formatted enough to highlight the problem. Other did not mention explicitly that **there are two different headers**, so the answers which suggested to use `request.format` put you in a very risky situation of checking the wrong thing.

First of all, Rails (verified with >=4.2) treats these headers as case-insensitive

```rb
request.headers['CONTENT_TYPE'] # "application/json"
request.headers['Content-type'] # "application/json"
request.headers['Content-Type'] # "application/json"
```

May be your question was related to previous Rails version, since it was asked in 2013.

To avoid messing with headers is better to use dedicated methods for that:

| Method | Header | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `request.content_type` | `Content-Type` | What a client is sending to you |
| `request.format` | `Accept` | What a client is expecting from you |