# How to set default format for routing in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

There is the following code for routing:

```
  resources :orders, only: [:create], defaults: { format: 'json' }
  resources :users,  only: [:create, :update], defaults: { format: 'json' } 
  resources :delivery_types, only: [:index], defaults: { format: 'json' }
  resources :time_corrections, only: [:index], defaults: { format: 'json' }
```

It is possible to set default format for all resources using 1 string without 'defaults' hash on each line? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the routing of different request types derived from the header request (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595424/request-format-returning/1595453#1595453), not in a param?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
scope format: true, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
  resources :orders, only: [:create]
  resources :users,  only: [:create, :update] 
  resources :delivery_types, only: [:index]
  resources :time_corrections, only: [:index]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather add method to application_controller. And use it as before filter where I want.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
...
private 
...
  def set_default_format
    params[:format] ||= "json"
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_default_format, only: [:create]
  ...
end
```

In this case default format wouldn't a surprise for new developers, because usually `routes.rb` is big and cumbersome

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

```
  scope defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    resources :users, only: [:index]
  end
```