# Set defaults for all Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

In Rails you can specify defaults for a group of routes (within a namespace) like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Other routes

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    resources :users
  end 
end
```

How can I apply defaults like this to all the routes within the application?

Comment: Not sure this is possible. But you can set the format in the `before_action` of your application controller (this is not the same though).

Comment: That's not a bad idea actually; I already have a `before_filter` that only allows requests with the format as JSON, but I could modify this to set the format to JSON if none is set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>I downvoted `Yury's` answer because it's inefficient.</s>

I originally presumed (incorrectly) you wanted to set a `constraint` (IE only accepting `JSON` mime types). If this was the case, [you'd benefit from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11791204/1143732):

```
scope format: true, constraints: { format: 'json' } do
  # your routes here
end
```

Since you're wishing to set a `default`, I still believe `Yury's` answer to be inefficient (you'd be better setting the mime type in the middleware, not the controller).

Thus, perhaps you could [use the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21017093/1143732):

```
#config/routes.rb
scope format: true, defaults: { format: "json" } do
  ...
end
```

Comment: I do only want to accept JSON requests, but using a `constraint` returns 404 for other request formats instead of 406. This looks like what I want, although I'm not familiar with `format: true`, what does it do?

Comment: Don't know - the guys on the other questions seemed to think it worked well. I think it means your scope has `format` enabled although I'd have to spend some time looking at it to know for sure

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Yury Lebedev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33689126/343486), I've got this working using a `before_action`. There is a difference to the route `defaults` option when using this method: `request.format` isn't set to `application/json` as it is using `defaults`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :default_format_json

  def default_format_json
    unless params.key?(:format)
      params[:format] = "json"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: one small thing: `before_filter` is deprecated in favor of `before_action`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the `before_action` globally:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_format

  def set_format
    return unless request.format.nil?
    request.format = :json
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. `request.format` is a MIME type, and this would override it if it's already set.

Comment: I added a check for nil to the `set_format` function. I think the `defaults` option for routes does the same

Comment: Even when the format isn't specified, `request.format` isn't `nil`, it's `text/html`.

Comment: I originally downvoted this, but then realized that you're trying to set a `default` not a `constraint`. This would work for a default, but not a constraint

Comment: @RichPeck Daniel wrote, that he already had a `before_action`, that only allows `json` format, that's why i just added the default value